# Using SQL Transactions for a single sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions

I have read a lot about SQL-transaction the pased few days.
But i have not found an answer to my question. So maybe someone here can solve my problem?

The exact question is: Should i use a sql transaction for a single select/update/insert statement?

Or is it to overact to use SQL transactions for a single sql statement?

Thanks...

regards
Ali

Comment: It depends what your query is. Transactions ensure that database is always consistent and you are sure that your query is either going to PASS or FAIL.

Comment: Yes i know that. But should i use always transactions in my application everytime i communicate with the database? Or is this overact? Can you tell me a very simple example where you recomend to use transactions and a simple example where you do not recomand to use sql transactions?

Comment: It would be pointless on a select statement. And if you don't specify an explicit transaction for a single insert or update it will use an implicit transaction. So any given update or insert is using a transaction. The time you would want an explicit one is if you need the state of the data to be rolled back across several statements. There is no harm in using a transaction for an insert/update, it is just more code to write for what is going to happen anyway.

Comment: GREAT. Thats what i thought ... Thank you for your answer :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Individual statements *implicitly* have their own transactions. By default, individual statements create and rollback/commit themselves. In theory, you can make it so that it will *behave* like an explicit transaction, although I can't think of a super great reason to do this. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-implicit-transactions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

The only reason I can think of to wrap an individual statement in its own *explicit* transaction is if you wanted to leave the transaction open so you could test something like blocking, or just maybe check the data while debugging before rolling it back.